# UITableViewCell does not deliver touch event to subview, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have added a subview to cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let l = MEL()
    l.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.contentView.addSubview(l)
    return cell
}
```

but when I touch label, touchesEnded does not get called, why?

```
class MEL: UILabel {

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
```

Comment: Override `func touchesCancelled(_ touches: NSSet!,
            withEvent event: UIEvent!)` in MEL and check the touch is cancelled or not

Comment: `touchesCancelled` not get called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tableView's frame height was set to 0, that is why touch event was not delivered.

Answer (score 0):

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) ->

UITableViewCell! {

```
let l = MEL()
l.userInteractionEnabled = true
cell.contentView.addSubview(l)
return cell
```